# Updating Storage Items Dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have the following two screens on my application, a login screen which authenticates the user and sets the user_meta items in storage. The profile screen grabs the user_meta item and displays it, however, when I change the user meta it works on the database side but I have no way on properly updating the storage to show this change.

**The problem**: My authentication screen and set storage items work perfectly, I can also properly display the user meta items on the profile screen. The problem is updating the storage items on profile screen if a user changes it.

```
////Login Screen////
  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView>
                    <Form>
                        <Item floatingLabel>
                            <Label>Email</Label>
                            <Input onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({email:text})} />
                        </Item>
                        <Item floatingLabel last>
                            <Label>Password</Label>
                            <Input secureTextEntry onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({password:text})} />
                        </Item>
                        <Button block success style={{ marginTop: 50 }} onPress={() => {
                                this.validate();
                        }} >
                            <Text>Authenticate</Text>
                        </Button>
                    </Form>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }

  validate(){
        this.setState({ validating: true });

        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('username', this.state.email);
        formData.append('password', this.state.password);

        return fetch('myLoginAPI', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
        })
            .then((response) => response.json())

            .then((responseJson) => {

                let data = responseJson;

                if (this.saveToStorage(data)){
                    this.setState({
                        validating: false
                    });
                }
            })
    }

      async saveToStorage(userData){
            if (userData) {
                await AsyncStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify({
                        authToken: userData.cookie,
                        id: userData.user.id,
                        userName: userData.user.username,
                        favoriteColor: userData.user.favoriteColor,
                    })
                );
            }
            return false;
        }
  }
```

```
////Profile Screen////
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      favoriteColor: ''
    };
  }

componentDidMount() {
    this.getFavoriteColor()
  }

getFavoriteColor = async () => {
AsyncStorage.getItem('user')
.then((value) => {
  const data = JSON.parse(value);
   this.setState({ favoriteColor: data.favoriteColor });
});
}
  changeFavoriteColor() {
    axios
         .get("myapi/userid='5'&metakey='favoriteColor'&value='blue'")
         .then(response => {
           alert(response.status);
         });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView/>
            <View>
            ///Displays Favorite Color from Storage///
            <Text>{this.state.favoriteColor}</Text>

           <Button
            onPress={() => this.changeFavoriteColor()}
            title="Change Favorite Color to Blue"
            />

            </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

This function, changeFavoriteColor(), does work and it changes the users meta on the database side so there is no problems with my API calls. I am unsure how to update the storage items too display this update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you are successfully storing data in the `DB`, but you are importing data from an asynchronous repository. Therefore, asynchronous storage data must also be changed.

```js
  async changeFavoriteColor() {
    let response = await axios.get("myapi/userid='5'&metakey='favoriteColor'&value='blue'")
    alert(response.status);
    let userdata = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user')
    let data = JSON.parse(userdata);
    data.favoriteColor = "blue"
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(data))
  }
```

Comment: Perfect, this works. I added: this.getFavoriteColor() before the closing bracket of your code so that it refreshes the state value on the profile screen with the adjusted storage item.